# Helm - unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am running the folwing commmand to install Helm chart.

```
helm install pt-sides-api --set env=dev,data_center_name=sl --set-string namespace="10475" -f values.yaml  --debug ./
```

But is is failing with the following error.

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: unable to decode "": json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field ObjectMeta.metadata.namespace of type string
helm.go:84: [debug] unable to decode "": json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field ObjectMeta.metadata.namespace of type string
unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest
```

I am not sure, what is wrong here.

I even tried to put namespace in values.yml but no luck.

```
namespace: !!string 10475
```

Comment: What is actually in your template code; do you need to `quote` a value?  Helm will normally install objects into the `helm install --namespace` of the release, and you don't usually need to directly specify a namespace name in your templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using single quotes around double quotes.

```
helm install pt-sides-api --set env=dev,data_center_name=sl --set-string namespace='"10475"' -f values.yaml  --debug ./
```